# kafka performance test arguments meaning

Tags: performance-testing, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I need to run some performance test with kafka.

I am using the guideline explained here:
https://engineering.linkedin.com/kafka/benchmarking-apache-kafka-2-million-writes-second-three-cheap-machines

It uses command like:
    bin/kafka-run-class.sh    org.apache.kafka.clients.tools.ProducerPerformance test7 50000000 100 -1 acks=1 bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092 buffer.memory=67108864 batch.size=8196

I undestand that:

name of topic: test7

num_records: 50000000

record_size: 100

server_address: bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092 buffer.memory=67108864

But I do not undestand the meaning of:

-1

acks=1

buffer.memory=67108864

batch.size=8196

Does anyone have a clear picture of what do they mean? Or do you know any documentation of this tool?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking deeper in the Apache Kafka page I found the table with the meaning of the Producer parameters.
They can be found at the following link:

http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#producerconfigs